# Encrypting any file using AES

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I'm using some code like this to encrypt a file.

```
            FileStream fsInput = new FileStream(ifile_path,
              FileMode.Open,
              FileAccess.Read);

            FileStream fsEncrypted = new FileStream(ofile_path,
               FileMode.Create,
               FileAccess.Write);
            AesCryptoServiceProvider AES = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
            AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            AES.KeySize = 256;
            iv = AES.IV;
            AES.Key = key;
            ICryptoTransform aesencrypt = AES.CreateEncryptor();
            CryptoStream cryptostream = new CryptoStream(fsEncrypted,
               aesencrypt,
               CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            byte[] bytearrayinput = new byte[fsInput.Length];
            fsInput.Read(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length);
            cryptostream.Write(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length);
            cryptostream.Close();
            fsInput.Close();
            fsEncrypted.Close();
```

However, while this code successfully encrypts .txt and .xml files, it doesn't work on other file types such as .docx, or image file formats. What changes can I make to the code to extend the functionality to all such file types?

Comment: Could it be the case that you open the file in text mode? To narrow down the problem you should test whether reading and writing out files works without encryption. If it doesn't throw out the encryption part of the question, if it does try whether you can find an input to the encryption part that does not decrypt properly and if possible throw out the IO stuff.

Comment: have you tried out bouncycastle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use a BinaryReader and BinaryWriter for doing the file I/O. The normal StreamReader will attempt to read the bytes using a particular encoding as it implements TextReader and will mangle primitive data types. This is why plain text .txt and .xml work while .docx files do not.

Comment: also add the code changes to make your answer more comprehensive